# How to automate citrix application using selenium java or python

Tags: selenium

Our Application is hosted on citrix . so we are unable to automate that application through selenium.

Because every time selenium launch it's own browser.and citrix having it's own browser.

could you suggest how we can do that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279876/can-we-automate-application-available-under-citrix-program-neighbourhood

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that testing over Citrix is a good idea.
What Citrix basically does is render a Windows application over the network.
I would just install a local instance of the application you are trying to test and perform your tests on that instance.